# Is it possible to call one RouteBuilder from another RouteBuilder in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have two different Processes. One read some csv file and store it in DB and other fetch the record from DB and calculate some value and store it in DB. I want to call the second process at the completion of the first. Is it possible to do this with the help of the camel.

Answer (score 2):

To 'call' another route when one route has finished you just send the exchange to that route with a `.to()` and the [direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) component.

```
from("file:/csv-drop/")
    .to(db:store)
    .to("direct:calculate-value-and-store")
```

in another route builder or the same route builder:

```
from("direct:calculate-value-and-store")
    .to(db:get)
    .process(new CalculateValueProcessor())
    .to(db:store)
```

This code above won't work but it gives you an idea of what using two routes looks like.

Answer (score 2):

You have many possibilities to connect one route to each other:

- **direct** component.
- **vm** component.
- **seda** component.
- **activemq**, **jms** components.
- **direct-vm** component.

More information can be found here: https://camel.apache.org/components.html

- **direct**, **direct-vm** - components for synchronous messaging.
- **seda**, **vm** - components for asynchronous, in-memory messaging.
- **activemq**, **jms** - components for asynchronous messaging through JMS.
- **direct-vm**, **vm** - in-memory messaging, can be used, to connect routes deployed in different OSGI Bundles, for example.